# Why does this speed up my SQL query?

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization, performance

I learned a trick a while back from a DBA friend to speed up certain SQL queries.  I remember him mentioning that it had something to do with how SQL Server compiles the query, and that the query path is forced to use the indexed value.

Here is my original query (takes 20 seconds):

```
select Part.Id as PartId, Location.Id as LocationId
 FROM Part, PartEvent PartEventOuter, District, Location 
WHERE 
    PartEventOuter.EventType = '600'   AND PartEventOuter.AddressId = Location.AddressId  
    AND Part.DistrictId = District.Id   AND Part.PartTypeId = 15   
    AND District.SubRegionId = 11   AND PartEventOuter.PartId = Part.Id  
    AND PartEventOuter.EventDateTime <= '4/28/2009 4:30pm'   
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT PartEventInner.EventDateTime  
            FROM PartEvent PartEventInner
            WHERE PartEventInner.PartId = PartEventOuter.PartId
                AND PartEventInner.EventDateTime > PartEventOuter.EventDateTime 
                AND PartEventInner.EventDateTime  <= '4/30/2009 4:00pm')
```

Here is the "optimized" query (less than 1 second):

```
select Part.Id as PartId, Location.Id as LocationId
 FROM Part, PartEvent PartEventOuter, District, Location 
WHERE 
    PartEventOuter.EventType = '600'   AND PartEventOuter.AddressId = Location.AddressId  
    AND Part.DistrictId = District.Id   AND Part.PartTypeId = 15   
    AND District.SubRegionId = 11   AND PartEventOuter.PartId = Part.Id  
    AND PartEventOuter.EventDateTime <= '4/28/2009 4:30pm'   
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT PartEventInner.EventDateTime  
            FROM PartEvent PartEventInner
            WHERE PartEventInner.PartId = PartEventOuter.PartId
                **AND EventType = EventType**
                AND PartEventInner.EventDateTime > PartEventOuter.EventDateTime 
                AND PartEventInner.EventDateTime  <= '4/30/2009 4:00pm')
```

Can anyone explain in detail why this runs so much faster?  I'm just trying to get a better understanding of this.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the query plan?

Comment: Because there's an index on eventtype?

Comment: Don't you have an index on this field?

Comment: Depends on your database engine, I'm assuming you're using SQL 2005/2008

Comment: Yes I have looked at it, but it doesn't mean anything to me.  The costs for the original show a 31% on a Clustered Index Scan (in addition to many other Clustered Index Scans).  The highest cost in the "optimized" version is an 8% Clustered Index Scan.

Comment: Note that if EventType is NULLable, then the 2 queries *are not the same* (as EventType = EventType would not be true if EventType IS NULL).

Comment: @samuel - Actually this "field" is a column within a View.  @hova - yes, this is SQL Server 2005 Express.

Comment: P.S.  There are no indexes on the PartEvent View's columns.

Comment: I think the point about the added condition excluding NULLs may be the explanation.  What if you replace that condition with `EventType IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Capture an XML query for each, and post them. Then we can get specific. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190646.aspx

Comment: Checking EventType IS NOT NULL did not speed up the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably because you are getting a Cartesian product without your EventType = EventType

From WikiPedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

"[SQL] makes it too easy to do a Cartesian join (joining all possible combinations), which results in "run-away" result sets when WHERE clauses are mistyped. Cartesian joins are so rarely used in practice that requiring an explicit CARTESIAN keyword may be warranted. (SQL 1992 introduced the CROSS JOIN keyword that allows the user to make clear that a Cartesian join is intended, but the shorthand "comma-join" with no predicate is still acceptable syntax, which still invites the same mistake.)"

you are actually going through more rows than necessary with your first query.

http://www.fluffycat.com/SQL/Cartesian-Joins/

Comment: Can't be...there's no table qualifier on EventType, so it's comparing it to itself. Essentially a no-op (except for NULLS, that is).

Comment: In my first attempts to optimize this query, I did in fact convert everything to (left) inner joins on the related fields. However, this did not impact the execution time one bit.

Answer (score 1):

Are there a large number of records with EventType = Null?
Before you added the aditional restriction your subquery would have been returning all those Null records, which would then have to be scanned by the Not Exists predicate for every row in the outer query... So the more you restrict what the subquery returns, the fewer the rows that have to be scanned to verify the Not Exists...

If this is the issue, it would probably be even faster if you restricted the records to EventType = '600' in the subquery as well....

```
Select Part.Id as PartId, Location.Id as LocationId 
FROM Part, PartEvent PartEventOuter, District, Location 
WHERE PartEventOuter.EventType = '600'   
    AND PartEventOuter.AddressId = Location.AddressId      
    AND Part.DistrictId = District.Id   
    AND Part.PartTypeId = 15       
    AND District.SubRegionId = 11   
    AND PartEventOuter.PartId = Part.Id      
    AND PartEventOuter.EventDateTime <= '4/28/2009 4:30pm'       
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT PartEventInner.EventDateTime                  
                    FROM PartEvent PartEventInner
                    WHERE PartEventInner.PartId =  PartEventOuter.PartId
                       AND EventType = '600'                        
                       AND PartEventInner.EventDateTime > PartEventOuter.EventDateTime
                       AND PartEventInner.EventDateTime  <= '4/30/2009 4:00pm')
```

Comment: That is just as fast, however wrong for our result set...  The subquery is correct as it was (any "EventType")

Answer (score 0):

Odd, do you have an index defined with both `EventType` and `EventDateTime` in it?

**Edit:**
Wait, is EventType a nullable column?
`Column = Column` will evaluate to `FALSE`* if it's value is `NULL`. At least using the default SQL Server settings.

The safer equivalent would be `EventType IS NOT NULL`. See it that gives the same result speed-wise?

---

*: My T-SQL reference says it should evaluate to `TRUE` with `ANSI_NULLS` set to `OFF`, but my query window says otherwise. ***confuzzled now***.
Any ruling? `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `NULL`or `UNKNOWN`? :) Gotta love 'binary' logic in SQL :(

Comment: No indexes on the PartEvent view's columns (on the tables the view is pulling from that is)

Comment: Will have to try "EventType IS NOT NULL" when I return to work Monday

Comment: Checking EventType IS NOT NULL did not speed up the query - it is still 20 seconds.  Checking if EventType = EventType still takes < 1 second.

Comment: Have you compared execution plans to shed some light on this? I'd love to know what is going on..

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses an index lookup if and only if all columns of this index are in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Every non-indexed column you add performs a table scan. If you narrow your query down earlier on in your WHERE clause, subsequent scans are faster. Thus by adding an Index scan, your table scans run against less data.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing used to be a lot more common than it is now.  Oracle 6 for instance used to be sensitive to the order in which you placed restrictions in the WHERE clauses.  The reason why you're surprised is really because we've become so good at expecting the DB engine to always work out the best access path no matter how you structure your SQL.  Oracle 6 & 7 (I switched to MSSQL after that) also had the hint extension which you could use to tell the database how it might like to construct the query plan.

In this specific case it's difficult to give a conclusive answer without seeing the actual query plans but I suspect the difference is you have a compound index which uses EventType which is not being employed for the first query but is for the second.  This would be unusual in that I'd expect your first query to have used it anyway, so I suspect that the database statistics may be out of date, so

**REGENERATE STATISTICS**

then try again and post the results here.